# Errors when freezing a Python application with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I'm trying to build a program in Python 3.6, but I've been struggling to get a functional .exe out. The packing script looks like it completes, but the resulting program instantly crashes. I've had similar issues with py2exe and pyinstaller even when using earlier versions of python 3, but I was able to get the following error out of cx_freeze 5.0.1's executable:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000019a0 (most recent call first):
```

Searching around this has been mentioned before in relation to unix systems, but I'm doing this on Windows 10?

Here's the packaging script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])

import sys
base = None
#'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [
    Executable('WorkingScript.py', base=base, targetName = 'WorkingScript.exe', icon='IconSml.ico')]]
    includefiles=["Logo3.png", "Image4.png", "IconSml.ico"]

setup(name='WorkingScript',
      version = '0.9',
      description = 'This time around',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

The only modules my program imports are tkinter, PIL, os, threading, csv and xml.dom.

Comment: What version of cx_freeze are you using? I had the same issue when using cx_freeze from withing a virtual environment. Fixed it by using `python -m venv` instead of `virtualenv`. Anyway this issue should be resolved by now, see the issue on Bitbucket: https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/131

Comment: This was 5.0.1, although I also had a go with 5.0 with no luck. I eventually managed to get PyInstaller to work with Python 3.4, so that works for now.